# Crop image with important part in bottomright corner

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I am designing an app that must look good on all android devices. In an activity i want to set the background. The image i want to use has an important figure in the right bottom corner 
What I want:
- maintain aspect ratio
- right bottom corner of original image must be visible
- fullscreen
- must work on portrait and landscape

I have tried all the scaletype options, the fit options don't fill the entire screen and the centercrop crops at all sides (so it slices of a part of the right bottom corner).

Comment: As said, fit options dont fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make an imageView for your drawable and customize it by changing `<ImageView>` to `<com.packagename.CenterCropShiftsUp>`, and set the scaleType to centerCrop.
Create CenterCropShiftsUp.java in the package I just mentioned, and use this code to shift the drawable upwards:

```
package nl.mijnverzekering.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CenterCropShiftsUp extends ImageView
{
   public CenterCropShiftsUp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b)
   {
      int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
      int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

      int viewWidth = r - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
      int viewHeight = b - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

      float heightRatio = 1 / ((float) drawableHeight / (float) viewHeight);
      float widthRatio = 1 / ((float) drawableWidth / (float) viewWidth);

      // Choose the biggest ratio as scaleFactor
      // (centerCrop does the same: the drawable never scales down to leave part of the screen empty)
      float scale = heightRatio > widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

      int newDrawableHeight = (int) (scale * (float) drawableHeight);

      // Shifts the t (top) of the imageFrame up (t -=)
      // This calculation aligns the bottom of the drawable to the bottom of the screen
      t -= (newDrawableHeight - b);

      return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
   }
}
```

It first calculates the scaleFactor of the image, then uses this scale to calculate the new drawableHeight (just as centerCrop would do it). With this height you can calculate how far the frame of the ImageView should be shifted upwards (using `setFrame()` to get the bottom of the drawable aligned to the bottom of the screen).

The alignment on the right, which you also requested, is of course automatically fixed due to the properties of centerCrop itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a litte bit late, nevertheless I want to post my answer. I needed to have a top left shifted view, whereas the width is always cropped. I found this library (https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView), but I decided to just use portions of it. It ended up in overriding `setFrame`and setting the scale type to `Matrix` in the constructor of my custom image view.

```
@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    boolean changed = super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);

    int viewWidth = r - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int viewHeight = b - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    if (viewHeight > 0 && viewWidth > 0) {
        final Matrix matrixCopy = new Matrix();
        matrixCopy.set(getImageMatrix());

        final Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        int drawableWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        float scale = scaleX > scaleY ? scaleX : scaleY;
        matrixCopy.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrixCopy);
    }
    return changed;
}
```